# Calculate the difference in time between two dates and add them to a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with +1M rows. It has a start_date and an end_date using the format `"aaaa-mm-dd hh-mm-ss"`.
I want to add a new column to the dataset with the duration of the time between the end and start date for each row.

So far, I'm able to get the time difference using the `difftime` function:

`difftime("2020-11-01 13:45:40", "2020-11-01 13:36:00", units = "mins")`

This gets me the following output: `Time difference of 9.666667 mins`, which I would like to replicate for the entire +1M-rows dataset.

For my test I'm working with a small tibble. I tried using the `mutate` function with `rowwise` and `list`. My code goes as follows:

```
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(trip_duration = list((difftime(as.Date(df$`end time`), as.Date(df$`start time`), units = "mins"))))
```

This provides the following output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  `start time`        `end time`          trip_duration
  <chr>               <chr>               <list>       
1 2020-11-01 13:36:00 2020-11-01 13:45:40 <drtn [3]>   
2 2020-11-01 13:36:00 2020-11-01 13:45:40 <drtn [3]>   
3 2020-11-01 13:36:00 2020-11-01 13:45:40 <drtn [3]>
```

The new column doesn't show what I'm looking for, it just shows the number `3` for each row no matter if I ask for the result in `mins`, `secs`, or even `hours`, and now I'm stuck trying to figure out the way to do the calculation.

Thanks in advance to anyone able to help, cheers!

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Can you use dput and give us a small sample of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code.

First and foremost, don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes. Pipes (`%>%`) were created to avoid using `df$column_name` everytime you want to use variable from the dataframe. Using `$` can have unintended consequences when grouping the data or using `rowwise` as you can see in your case.

Secondly, `difftime` is vectorised so no need of `rowwise` here.

Finally, if you want time difference in minutes you should change the values to `POSIXct` type and not dates. Try the following -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(trip_duration = difftime(as.POSIXct(`end time`), 
                                  as.POSIXct(`start time`), units = "mins"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but I wanted to add a `lubridate` approach.

First, import and ensure your columns are in the correct format:

```
library(lubridate)
df$`end time`<- lubridate::as_datetime(df$`end time`)
df$`start time` <- lubridate::as_datetime(df$`start time`)
```

Then simply add the column (ensure you put the latest date first, or you'll get a negative number):

```
df$trip_duration <- time_length(df$`end time` - df$`start time`, unit="days")
```